# In R, is there any idea that convert number to text?

Tags: r, function

I wanna make function that print "three hundred twenty four" when the input is c(3,2,4).

and "four thousand one hundred thirty two" when the input is c(4,1,3,2).

I can make "324" , "4132" using paste()

but I can make it further.

Is there any good idea?

Answer (score 0):

use library `english`

```
install.packages("english")
library(english)

english(123)
[1] one hundred and twenty-three
```

Comment: useful library ! thanks !